# change image width and height while window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the width and height of the image while resizing the window in jquery, i have a sample site but that code is hard to me.

The sample site is http://xctravels.com/  Here we can see the dynamic change in width and height of image while window resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/uEzNj/4/

**JavaScript**

```
var lastSize = { width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() };
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    var win = $(window);
    $('img').each(function (i, img) {
        img = $(img);
        var w = img.width(),
            h = img.height();
        img.width(w + win.width() - lastSize.width);
        img.height(w + win.height() - lastSize.height);        
    });
    lastSize = { width: win.width(), height: win.height() };
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.resize event

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
//Your code
}
```

Example:

```
<body>
    <script>
        window.onresize=function(){
        if ($("#imageresize").width()>200 && $("#imageresize").height()>200){
            $("#imageresize").width($("#imageresize").width()-parseInt(10));
            $("#imageresize").height($("#imageresize").height()-parseInt(10));
        }
        }
    </script>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" width="800" height="400" id="imageresize"/>
</body>
```

The above example is just to resize image while resize window.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version of resize is this:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
 });
```

more info here: http://api.jquery.com/resize/